# How to get the list of defined models in loopback.js?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I created a Loopback.js application and defined models talking to a datasource. All is ok in Loopback explorer. 
server.js is working fine.
In the /server folder, I created another js file that does contain:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();
console.log(app.models());
```

When running that file, no models are shown.
The result is: `[]`.
This is an empty array.

Any idea why I cannot get the whole models list?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let app = require('../../server/server'); /** make sure the path to server is right **/

console.log(app.models)
```

if you want to access specific model

```
console.log(app.models.modelName);
```

Comment: I am getting the models. Thanks for that. Any idea how I could make an independent file to be sure to not use server.js ? My plan is to have this js file running on another server. I required serve.js and thing are ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference of the loopback app object (also the way to retrieve the models) is incorrect. You cannot require loopback and expect the app instance. In loopback.js, the entry script is `server/server.js` which initialises the app, and runs necessary processes to lift it on defined port. Loopback application has a `server/boot` directory where resides the files which are executed as soon as the app is ready *and models are available*. Move your file to the boot directory with necessary modifications.

Also, for a model to be available in loopback app scope-- you've to add the model to `model-config.json`

Eg.

```
 {
    "ModelOne": {
       "dataSource": "mysql",
       "public": false
    },
    "ModelTwo": {
       "dataSource": "db",
       "public": false
    },
    "YourModel": {
        "dataSource": "mysql", // this value comes from datasources.json -- well, remove this line because json file doesn't support comments
        "public": false
    }
 }
```

Now, `YourModel` is bound to the app and is accessible via `app` object or any current model. For example:

```
app.models.YourModel
```

`app` instance is attached to every valid model so you can access another model without having to `require` or `import` it by the following way:
(Assuming, you're in model-one.js file)

```
ModelOne.app.models.YourModel
```

(Not writing code for you! Remember, they key is to learn from the community and implement it ourselves)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the input. My thing is I created, and really need, another js file that is called on particular requests. In that file,I would like to be able to access the models. I would like to be able not to require server.js but store everything in an external js file.